# Como utilizar o save no Node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Estou com um projeto de estudos utilizando Node JS com MongoDB e estou tendo dificuldade de salvar um registro no banco, estou utilizando o método dessa forma.

```
function postRestaurant (req, res) {
    var restaurants = new Restaurants(req.body);
    restaurants
    .save
    ((err, restStored) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message: 'Error do servidor'});
        }else{
            if(!restStored){
                res.status(404).send({message: 'No existe restaurant'});
            }else{
                res.status(200).send({restaurants: restStored});
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Quando vou submeter o método ele está caindo no erro 500, onde será que estou errado?

Comment: Dê um `console.log(err)`, para ver qual o motivo do erro.

Comment: Não está faltando passar o objeto que será salvo? Só estou vendo a função de callback, sem o registro em si.